# Как получить куки, которые пришли от сервера?

Tags: reactjs, express, cookie, сессия

Есть небольшое приложение на React+Express. На Express у меня `express-session` установлен. Он мне присылает куку, которая идет не в хранилище само, а отображается только в ответе сервера (вкладка сети в режиме разработчика в браузере)
Что-то наподобии такого (знаю, что картинки нежелательно присылать)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне в React получить доступ к этом куке?

Comment: `document.cookie` не работает. Эта кука не идет в глобальное хранилише куков. Библиотеки для куков тоже

Comment: Если на скриншоте «Http...» это HttpOnly, то значит никак — HttpOnly существует специально для того чтобы javascript-код не мог получить куки